# Double integral over a triangle

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, triangles, plane-geometry

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function (derivable, integrable over all of $\mathbb{R}^2$). Let $T$ be a triangle in $\mathbb{R}^2$, defined by its vertices : $A=(x_a,y_a)$, $B=(x_b,y_b)$, $C=(x_c,y_c)$. Let $I$ be the integral of $f$ over $T$ :
$$ I = \iint_T f(x,y)dxdy$$
Is there a generic formula for $I$ based on $f$, $x_a,y_a$, $x_b,y_b$, $x_c,y_c$ ?

EDIT :
In my case, $f(x,y)=cos(x)$

Comment: No, you should compute the integral by means of some Fubini-like reduction. The fact that $f$ is independent of one variable can be useful, of course.

Comment: Depending on $A, B, C$ and $f$ I would consider to apply a linear transformation which maps the triangle to, say, $\{ (x,y) : 0<x<1, 0< y < 1-x \} $, which makes determination of the bounds of integration less cumbersome. I may make $f$ more complicated, though...